# How can i build an good component(Dagger) listener in android?

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to write a component with dagger2 for my app. The idea is that the component do all the service work and return objects to the Activity. So far so good...but, now i'm trying to build the listener part that will make the bridge through Activity and Component, there is any way to build that without making several interfaces(delegate like) or making one and then doing a loot of if's/else's .

Comment: ...the component just provides things defined in its modules or objects defined to be in that component's scope. I don't understand what `listener that will make the bridge through Activity and Component` means, unless you're just looking for an [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components in dagger 2 shouldn't do service work, they are simply a bridge between your modules and the class that you need to inject with the objects provided by said modules.

Another way to put it: components don't return objects to the activity, they inject objects into the activity whose construction is defined in the modules.

What you need is to create a separate object that does whatever you need to do and then returns to the activity, this object can be injected using dagger, but it is not Dagger 2 related.